# Expectation of a Random Walk

Tags: random-walk

I am researching Random Walks and trying to find how to get their expectations. 
I have studied Markov chains before. I have found one way of getting the expected number of steps to reach a state by using generating functions.

Can anyone tell me if you can use Markov chain methods such as a limiting matrix or fundamental matrix to find the expected number of steps for the RW?

Thanks!